# How to smooth a probability density function to cover all real numbers

Tags: probability

For a personal research project, I have data and its log likelihood $\ell(\theta)$ will depend on the density of the data's distribution. My data is sampled according to a standard sine wave. In other words, the data points I have, $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, are all such that $|x_i| \le 1$, and most values are close to 1 or -1.

From differentiating the CDF of the sine function, I believe that the density of the data's distribution is $f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{1-x^2}}$ if $|x| < 1$ and $0$ otherwise. This does integrate to one. Unfortunately, it is a discontinuous function.

I was hoping to use a stochastic gradient method to find the optimal parameter value, but in order to do that, I have to take gradients, and I'm a little worried about the discontinuity of $f$. From reading various online notes (e.g., [here](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~lebanon/notes/mle.pdf)), it seems like stochastic gradient is out, so what are some smooth functions that approximate $f$? I'm having some trouble thinking of functions that follow the form of $f$, but "round out" at -1 and 1 and then go back (slowly) to zero. Any advice/thoughts?

Comment: Have you thought about using a gradient-free method like the [Nelder-Mead simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) or implementations or Thomas Rowan's [Subplex](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Algorithms#Sbplx_.28based_on_Subplex.29)? There are a number of tools which implement one or both of those methods.

Comment: Yes, I will likely have to use those methods; I just wanted to see if anyone had a good function approximation for a gradient-specific approach.